# A technique adopted from a paper

Tags: citations, journals

Can we use a technique (equations and approach) from a journal paper in one section of our paper if we cite it like this: "Method X has been adopted from [Y], modified, and used in this paper"?

Answer (score 4):

> Method X has been adopted from [Y], modified, and used in this paper

I don't see why not. This is acceptable. In fact that is the most common form of citations you tend to see in papers that make an improvement over an existing method.

Just make sure you know ample knowledge of what you cite in this case as you are to make a modification to what is published. It would be best to know well about what *X* really is before you try to modify it.

Answer (score 3):

That is why citations exist. You always rely on other researchers results. That is why science can make progress. You can leave certain fields blackboxed, as others already have robusts methods developed which you can rely on.

I would assume that most scientist take it as an honor, if their method is reused. You just have to make sure to cite your source of knowledge.

If you describe your modification, it is also necessary to give a summary of the original method. State why it does not work in your applied case and describe the solution - your modification.

Try to avoid citations, when the status reaches a point, where the results are common sense. No researcher in our time cites Turing, yet we all use computers. Make sure this common sense though applies also to your research field. A computer science method which is teached in informatics first class might still just be known to informaticians. If you consider this method should be applied more in your non informatics field, cite it to give it visibility.